# Reloading UITextView from another UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I have 2 view controllers `MainDetailViewController` (MD) and `MainEditViewController` (ME)

There is a textView in MD with some text already there when view loads. Then I call ME like this

```
MainEditViewController *editVC = [[MainEditViewController alloc] init];
editVC.theTextView.text = self.theTextView.text;
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editVC];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am passing the TextView's text value to ME like above and calling it with presentViewController method.

In ME I edit the text and click on save button which should update the text value in MD's textView

```
MainDetailViewController *mainDetailVC = [[MainDetailViewController alloc] init];
mainDetailVC.theTextView.text = self.theTextView.text;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is not reflecting change in MD

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use a delegate for that. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers

Comment: @JordanMontel It doesn't work. Any other method?

Comment: I think your code doesn't work :) Add it

Comment: lOl I was doing that wrong. My protocol was not found :) so I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160887/cannot-find-protocol-declaration-for and bingo! Thanks a ton Bro 
Add this as your answer and I'll vote it up

Comment: You're welcome. I added an answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using block.
Add new block typedef to your  MainDetailViewController.h file just after imports but before @interface:

```
typedef void (^ReturnBlock)(NSString *arg);
```

In MainEditViewController.h file between @interface and @end add public property:

```
@property(copy) ReturnBlock returnBlock;
```

This is your block which will be called when you dismiss your ME view controller.
Next move to MainEditViewController.m file and replace code in save button from:

```
MainDetailViewController *mainDetailVC = [[MainDetailViewController alloc] init];
mainDetailVC.theTextView.text = self.theTextView.text;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

to:

```
    if (self.returnBlock)
        self.returnBlock(self.theTextView.text);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You should use popViewControllerAnimated: method instead of dismissViewControllerAnimated.

The last change left to do is in your MainDetailViewController.m file when you create editVC, add after:

```
editVC.theTextView.text = self.theTextView.text;
```

this:

```
editVC.returnBlock = ^(NSString *returnText) {
    NSLog(@"Returned text: %@", returnText);
    self.theTextView.text = returnText;
};
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your help. I will surely try your method as well.

Comment: I think solution with block is better because you keep your logic in one class. With delegate you have to keep it in multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Views are not loaded until you present the view, so you will need to create a property to hold that string value and in viewDidLoad, you should set the textfield with the string value.

Comment: I suspect my MD view doesn't reload when I dismiss ME view and that might be the reason its not updating.

Comment: How can I hold the value of child view controller in parent view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a protocol to retrieve data from B to A.

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160887/cannot-find-protocol-declaration-for).