# cannot find protocol declaration for delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

these 2 are the files where i m creating a protocol and then declare the delegate in another class

**this is my favouriteViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@class FavouritesTableViewController;

@protocol FavouritesTableViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>

- (void)senDetailsViewController:(FavouritesTableViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSArray *)item;

@end

@interface FavouritesTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchController *search;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id < FavouritesTableViewControllerDelegate > delegate;
@end
```

**and this is my viewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "FavouritesTableViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,FavouritesTableViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *weatherIcon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Place;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Temperature;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *unit;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *weatherText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *Info;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *summary;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *longitude;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *latitude;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *locationName;
@property BOOL setLocation;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;

- (IBAction)forecast:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)Share:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)history:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activIndicator;

- (IBAction)favbutton:(id)sender;

@end
```

the error i get is

> :- Cannot find protocol declaration for
>   'FavouritesTableViewControllerDelegate'

I'm declaring these methods and protocols to pass data from `FavouriteViewController` to `ViewController`

and this is the protocol method which i call in `ViewController.m`

```
-(void)senDetailsViewController:(FavouritesTableViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSArray *)item
{
    controller.delegate = self;
    self.latitude = [item[0] valueForKey:@"lat"];
    self.longitude = [item[0] valueForKey:@"long"];
    self.locationName = [item[0] valueForKey:@"name"];
    self.setLocation = YES;
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: It seems that you declared it in `favouriteViewController.h` but included another `FavouritesTableViewController.h`

Comment: Refer this - [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160887/cannot-find-protocol-declaration-for) Seems like a similar problem.

Comment: @PulkitSharma nope i have seeen that post its not the problem i am facing thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ths is happening because of recursive import, in `FavouritesTableViewController` you are importing `"ViewController.h"` and again `ViewController.h` you are importing "`FavouritesTableViewController.h`"

try

```
@class viewController;
@class FavouritesTableViewController;
```

in `FavouritesTableViewController.h` and remove `"#import ViewController.h"`

Comment: if in FavouriteViewController.h
i try @class viewController
it gives me an error asking for type

Comment: the methods in the protocol isnt getting called.. when i go to ViewController

Comment: in ViewController.m did you gave `.delegate` = self to FavouriteViewController object?

Comment: i have... it seems to be some other problem. i was referring to this article to pass data
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)
have done exactly the same

Comment: show where you declared .delegate = self in VIewcontroller.m and the method `senDetailsViewController: didFinishEnteringItem` in ViewController.m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103610/discussion-between-shravan-and-rahul-patel).