# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate' in -Swift.h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I tried to convert my objective C AppDelegate to Swift AppDelegate. So I deleted the main.m file and Converted all the AppDelegate code to swift. I tried to run the project, then this error occurs.

> Cannot find protocol declaration for
>   'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'

In the -Swift.h file they generate, this is the delegate they showed

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter * _Nonnull)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification * _Nonnull)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^ _Nonnull)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler SWIFT_AVAILABILITY(ios,introduced=10.0);
```

This is how I have written

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    handleNotification(notification.request.content.userInfo)
}
```

Please help me get what is the issue am facing.

I tried, cleaning, restarting Xcode and restarting my Mac. Am using Swift 3.2.

This is my -Swift.h file error
[image]

If I comment the delegates, there are no errors.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160887/cannot-find-protocol-declaration-for It all depends on your Objective C imports. You have not shown them so who knows what you’re doing. Clearly your conversion to Swift is very incomplete, and you have also deleted the main file prematurely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange fix but by importing #import  in my bridging header the issue was resolved.

Comment: Which is what I said, and what the duplicate said.

Comment: can u post the import?  my code is #import "UserNotifications.h" but got error 'UserNotifications.h' file not found

Answer (score 0):

You need to import following framework: import UserNotifications

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to proceed

```
import UIKit 
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        registerForPushNotification() 
        return true
    }

   /**Register for push notification*/
   func registerForPushNotification() {
       let userNotification = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
       userNotification.delegate = self
       userNotification.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .badge, .alert]) { (status, error) in
        if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // From iOS 10 onwards we need to call pushNotification registration method in main thread.
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
      }
   }

}


// MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.sound, .badge, .alert])
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to `#import` required framework in **BridgingHeader.h** to solve the problem

- e.g

> `#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>`