# Objective C protocol - some stupidly basic help needed, please

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I'm having a problem when I try to add a second protocol.  The first one is working just fine.  So I created a test application to try out using two protocols (because I'm still learning how to use protocols).  I do not know why I am having so much trouble understanding protocols.  I've even gone through tutorials and still struggle with them.

My first issue when I tried to add the second protocol and use it I received the following error:

> Assigning to ‘id’ from incompatible type ‘ *const _strong'

**But, let's ignore that for now**, because my test application is giving me this error for both protocols in my test app:

> Cannot find protocol declaration

So, I will post the code for my test application, because I **MUST understand the basics** before tackling more difficult issues.

**DelegateA Header**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol IDDelegateADelegate <NSObject>
@end

@interface IDDelegateA : NSObject
//other properties here
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<IDDelegateADelegate> delegateA;
@end
```

**DelegateA Implementation**

```
#import "IDDelegateA.h"

@implementation IDDelegateA
@synthesize delegateA;
//other methods and properties go here
@end
```

**DelegateB Header**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol IDDelegeteBDelegate <NSObject>
@end

@interface IDDelegeteB : NSObject
//other properties here
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<IDDelegeteBDelegate> delegateB;
@end
```

**DelegateB Implementation**

```
#import "IDDelegeteB.h"

@implementation IDDelegeteB
@synthesize delegateB;
//other methods and properties go here
@end
```

**The test class Header that uses these delegates**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "IDDelegateA.h"
#import "IDDelegeteB.h"

@interface IDTestingDelegates : NSObject <IDDelegateA, IDDelegateB>

@end
```

Right here I receive the `Cannot find protocol declaration` error for both delegates.  I've been searching on SO as well as going through tutorials and sample code.  Best answer on SO was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447573/cannot-find-protocol-declaration).  But I'm just not getting what I'm doing wrong.  Can somebody please point out what I am missing here?

Comment: Minor misspelling, you have `IDDelegeteB` in its header and implementation, but you refer to `IDDelegateB` in the test class...  It would be a good idea to correct all misspellings before proceeding further.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it had to be something really stupid.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@interface IDTestingDelegates : NSObject <IDDelegateA, IDDelegateB>
```

should be

```
@interface IDTestingDelegates : NSObject <IDDelegateADelegate, IDDelegeteBDelegate>
```

You have to list the *protocols* in `<...>`, not interfaces.

Comment: Just before you posted this, I realized my error.  Between the misspelling and the wrong protocol declaration, I sure mucked up what should have been an easy test, huh.

Comment: Oh, man, I was doing the same thing in the real code.  Fixed that and it fixed my first error.  Thank you!!!!!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

@interface declares a class, while the `ClassName <X>` syntax expects X to be a protocol (in your declaration of `IDTestingDelegates`).

Not sure exactly what you were trying to achieve here.

Comment: Just a test to try to understand protocols.  Now, I'm going to try to use both of these in my test app and see if I can recreate the first issue I was having.  Thank you for your help.  +1 for you.  :-)

Comment: Yup, fixed it in the real code and that fixed my first problem.  All works fine now.  Thanks again.