# Pass Data VC Delegates iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have two VC: StepThreeViewController and QuoteViewController.
I am trying to pass data back from QuoteViewController to StepThreeViewController by using a Delegate b/c once I have the data, I want to pop/dismiss the QuoteViewController and pass the data into StepThreViewController.

I'm getting an error that the Delegate Protocol is not found! I followed a youtube tutorial and read a lot of comments on StackOverflow but can not seem to find the error!

I also made sure that my #import of header files were there.

the GitHub to my code is found here:
https://github.com/aspirasean/BoxRocket.git

Thanks!

Comment: I think you might upload wrongly to Github. I only see .h and .m file. There is no project file nor storyboard file.

Comment: @Ricky the project is now uploaded on my git repository but to prevent it from crashing you'll need to enter your own Parse API key in the AppDelegate.m. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @Ricky I have it passing "heightField" but I put that as a place holder. I am ultimately trying to pass back "int quote" from the QuoteViewController and display it in the 'quoteLabel' in the StepThreeViewController.

Answer (score 2):

I think under `QuoteViewController.h`you have imported `"StepThreeViewController.h`" which might not be needed. I have commented out that line and it can compile without any error.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import "StepThreeViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

In case if you need to use **StepThreeViewController** in **QuoteViewController**, you might want to take a look at this post: [Cannot find protocol declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447573/cannot-find-protocol-declaration)

**Update**:

Under **StepThreeViewController.h** you should have:-

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong)  QuoteViewController *controller;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, you should

```
self.controller.delegate=self;
```

You will have to make the **StepThreeViewController** to be the delegate of the **QuoteViewController** in order for the **delegate method** to work.

To learn more about the delegate in Objective-C, you may visit: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Comment: you know, that worked! I'll need to now figure out if the data actually passed back. Thanks for the help!

Comment: now the method i've created in the StepThreeViewController is not being called when in QuoteViewController I am calling [self.delegate transferQuote:@"STRING"]; any ideas?