# Delegate was not declared?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have some view controller called `mainContainer` , he than import some other view controller called `myPills`, and add it as a subview .

the `mainContainer` also has a `protocol` to send delegates to the `myPills` class, and it looks like :

```
//mainContainer.h
@protocol mainScrollerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)function;

@end

@interface MainContainerView : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Than, obviously in the `myPills` class i cant import the `mainContainer` view, but i do want to register to the `mainContainer` delegates.

so in `myPills`

```
@interface MyPillsView : UIViewController <mainScrollerDelegate>
```

will give error on compile .

I have read this,and tried to move the import to be under the delegates-no success.(same error  that delegate was undeclared)

[Cannot find protocol declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447573/cannot-find-protocol-declaration)

How can you listen to a delegate in classB from classA , where classA is importing classB , so classB cant import A back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your protocol declaration in its own `Protocols.h` file, for example:

```
//Protocols.h
@protocol mainScrollerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)function;

@end
```

Then, just import it into both the controller who is sending the delegate methods, and the delegate itself:

```
#import "Protocols.h"

@interface MyPillsView : UIViewController <mainScrollerDelegate>
```

This method will keep all your protocols organized and can help remove circular imports.

Sidenote: You should really use the class naming convention for your protocol (ie `MainScrollerDelegate`).

Comment: so how does the protocols.h should look like ? what kind of file i create in Xcode? and what did you mean by your sidetone ? thanks very much!

Comment: My block of code after `//Protocols.h` is literally all the code needed in that file. Just create a header file in Xcode. My sidenote had a capital `M` instead of a lowercase `m` - it helps distinguish between variables and classes.

Comment: btw where you put the  @property(nonatomic,assign) id <mainScrollerDelegate> delegate;    ??