# Import two objective-c protocols in each others file ends with compiler errors

Tags: objective-c

there are two protocols, each in its own file:

```
// PMAService.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PMAPost.h"
#import "PMAServiceProcessingDelegate.h"

@protocol PMAService <NSObject>

-(void)setupService;
-(BOOL)processPost:(PMAPost *)post withDelegate:(id<PMAServiceProcessingDelegate>)delegate;

@end

// PMAServiceProcessingDelegate.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PMAPost.h"
#import "PMAService.h"

@protocol PMAServiceProcessingDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)successfullyProcessedPost:(PMAPost *)post by:(id<PMAService>)service;
-(void)notProcessedPost:(PMAPost *)post by:(id<PMAService>)service withError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

each of the protocols needs the opposite for a method declaration. as soon as i create the import in each of the files, the compiler is not able to compile anymore since it tells me that it cannot find one of the protocols.

**error messages for `PMAService.h` (for the #import statement of `PMAServiceProcessingDelegate.h`)**

- 'PMAServiceProcessingDelegate.h' file not found

**error messages for `PMAServiceProcessingDelegate.h` (one for each method declaration):**

- Cannot find declaration for 'PMAService'
- Cannot find declaration for 'PMAService'

is there something i missed out? isn't it allowed to import protocols like this?

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question but might be relevant: are your two protocol .h files included in the list of files in your project?  In other words, can they can be seen on the left side of your Xcode window, with all the other .m & .h files?  Also, [a potentially helpful question previously asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737148/cannot-find-protocol-declaration-in-xcode).

Comment: hi micheal. yeah, they are. albertamg below already solved my problem with a forward declaration... thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a *circular dependency* that you can solve using a *forward declaration*:

```
// PMAService.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PMAPost.h"

@protocol PMAServiceProcessingDelegate;

@protocol PMAService <NSObject>

-(void)setupService;
-(BOOL)processPost:(PMAPost *)post withDelegate:(id<PMAServiceProcessingDelegate>)delegate;

@end
```

Comment: and thats all? i only have to do this on one of the files? ... strange, it really works :-) never saw a concept like this. thank you!